# How to filter list elements in Haskell based on previous value in the list?

Tags: list, haskell, filter, functional-programming

I'm working on creating a function in Haskell that filters the numbers of a list on a condition based on the previous element in the list.

Example

the previous number is a multiple of 2

```
myFunction [1, 2, 5, 6, 3]
# expected output:
[5,3]
```

I know how to apply `filter` but so far I have seen that the filters take only one argument at a time.

I tried with `scanl1`, `foldl1`, and `map` but I'm new to Haskell and I have not been able to do so; any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit

It should be:

```
myFunction []       =  []
myFunction [x]      =  []
myFunction [x,y]    =  if (x `mod` 2) == 0 then [y] else []
myFunction (x:y:xs) =  if (x `mod` 2) == 0 
                      then y : (myFunction xs)
                      else myFunction (y:xs)
```

because for the input:

```
myFuntion [1, 2, 5, 6, 3]
```

the correct output should be:

```
[5,3]
```

Comment: I was a bit lost with the filters, I thought I had to use that combined with the fold to iterate over two elements at a time, I'm still in the imperative world, thanks a lot, I will have to study a bit more to understand this example and the (x:y:xs) notation :)

Comment: @FrederickÁlvarez I use this pattern matching when I need to go throw the list consuming two elements each time, you can also read a little more about fold1, sometimes is useful too

Comment: @FrederickÁlvarez `let xs = [1, 2, 5, 6, 3] in [ y | (x,y) <- zip xs (drop 1 xs), even x]` is also a possibility.  I see now that another answer already uses the `zip` function, but with list comprehensions the code can be clearer (although you did ask for `filter`).

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use library functions, there is a known trick for this sort of situations, which consists in zip'ing the input with its own tail, that is the initial list minus its first element.

```
 λ> 
 λ> inls = [1, 2, 5, 6, 3]
 λ> 
 λ> let pairs = zip (tail inls) inls
 λ> pairs
 [(2,1),(5,2),(6,5),(3,6)]
 λ>
```

and the resulting pair list is then an easy target for `map` and `filter`.
As in:

```
λ> let myFunction ls = let pairs = zip (tail ls) ls  in  map fst $ filter (even . snd) pairs
λ> 
λ> ls
 [1,2,5,6,3]
λ> 
λ> myFunction ls
[5,3]
λ>
```