# Map function applied to specific elements of the list

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, map-function

I have a function:

```
mapAtOriginal :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
mapAtOriginal f is xs = helper 0 is xs
  where
    helper _ [] xs = xs
    helper c (i:is) (x:xs)
      | c < i     =   x : helper (c+1) (i:is) xs
      | otherwise = f x : helper (c+1)    is  xs
```

It works like this:

```
mapAtOriginal (*2) [0,3] [1,2,3,4]   -- == [2,2,3,8]
```

So I want to rewrite it but using a **`map`** function. I understand that *`map`* applies to every element of the list, however, I need it applied only for specific indices.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` doesn't know “where in the list” it is. So you first need to encode that information into the elements themselves. This can be done with `zip [0..]`, which basically annotates each element with position at which it occurs.

Then, in the function you `map`, you just need to pattern-match on the annotation-tuple, and use an `if` to decide whether or not to apply the manipulator function to the other tuple element.

Note that the combination of `zip` and `map` is always equivalent to a single pass [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith), so that's what you should preferrably use.

Comment: @osobennyj Yes, or using `map ... (zip ...)` as mentioned above, which is `zipWith` in disguise.

Comment: or with list comprehension, `[ foo x | (i,x) <- zip [0..] xs, elem i is]`. this raises interesting concern, as it's unnecessarily quadratic, so the question becomes how to make it linear (in the indexes). one way is with a [stateful foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075309/849891), with the indexes as the state.

Comment: turns out, zipping and left-biased union was the way to go. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `map` to solve this problem, a possible route consists in making use of an auxiliary list of type `[(a, Bool)]`, where only the indexed elements are paired with a `True` boolean value.

The function producing this auxiliary list could be declared like this:

```
markIndexedElements :: [Int] -> [a] -> [(a, Bool)]
```

If we have such a function, the rest of our problem becomes easy:

```
 λ> auxList = markIndexedElements [0,3] [1,2,3,4]
 λ> auxList
 [(1,True),(2,False),(3,False),(4,True)]
 λ> 
 λ> map  (\(x, b) -> if b then (2*x) else x)  auxList
 [2,2,3,8]
 λ>
```

The `markIndexedElements` function makes a second list out of the first list, while maintaining some *state* information. So if we prefer a ready-made recursion scheme, it seems to be a job for the [scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) function.

The *state* to be maintained consists mostly of the current position in the original list plus the list of so far unused indices. If the current position is equal to the next index, we drop that index and output an (x, True) pair. This gives the following code:

```
-- only indexed elements to get paired with a True value
markIndexedElements :: [Int] -> [a] -> [(a, Bool)]
markIndexedElements indices xs =
    let  sfn ((_,p),(pos,ind)) y =  -- stepping function for scanl
             if (null ind)
               then ((y, False), (pos+1,[]))
               else ((y, pos==head ind),
                     (pos+1, if (pos==head ind)  then  tail ind  else  ind))
         scanRes = scanl  sfn  ((undefined,False), (0,indices))  xs
    in   map fst  $  drop 1 scanRes
```

The rest of the code is not difficult to write:

```
mapAtOriginal :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
mapAtOriginal fn indices xs =
    let  pairList  = markIndexedElements indices xs   -- auxiliary list
         pfn (x,b) = if b then (fn x) else x          -- auxiliary function
    in   map pfn pairList


main = do
    let  xs      = [1,2,3,4]
         indices = [0,3]
         result  = mapAtOriginal (*2) indices xs
    putStrLn $ show (markIndexedElements indices xs)
    putStrLn $ show result
```

### Program output:

```
[(1,True),(2,False),(3,False),(4,True)]
[2,2,3,8]
```

### Similar solutions:

If we try to apply just one more step of Cartesian reductionism to this problem, we can note that argument `xs` plays only a minor role in the `markIndexedElements` function. A possibility is to eliminate it completely, and have instead a function that returns just an unlimited list of boolean values:

```
booleansFromIndices :: [Int] -> [Bool]
booleansFromIndices indices =
    let  sfn (pos,ind) =  Just $  -- stepping function for unfoldr
             if (null ind)
               then ( False, (pos+1, []) )
               else ( pos==head ind,
                      (pos+1, if (pos==head ind)  then  tail ind  else  ind))
    in   unfoldr  sfn  (0,indices)
```

The resulting list ends with an unlimited sequence of `False` values after the last index:

```
 λ> take 10 $ booleansFromIndices [0,3]
 [True,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False]
 λ>
```

The target `mapAtOriginal` function can then be rewritten using `booleansFromIndices`:

```
mapAtOriginal :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
mapAtOriginal fn indices xs =
    let  pairList   = zip xs $ booleansFromIndices indices
         pfn (x, b) = if b  then  (fn x)  else  x
    in   map pfn pairList
```

Last but not least, as already noted by other answerers/commenters, the map+zip scheme can generally be replaced by one based on the [zipWith](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=zipWith) function.
Like this, in our case:

```
mapAtOriginal :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
mapAtOriginal fn indices xs =
    let  booleans = booleansFromIndices indices
    in   zipWith  (\x b -> if b  then  (fn x)  else  x)  xs  booleans
```

Comment: great idea, to stretch the index list so it matches up with the xs.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the idea from [jpmarinier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11282404/jpmarinier)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092535/849891) of filling up the empty spaces in the indices list; using package `data-ordlist`,

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import qualified Data.List.Ordered    as   O
import           Data.Ord  (comparing)

mapAtOriginal :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
mapAtOriginal f is xs = 
  zipWith (flip ($))                        -- apply zippily
    xs
    (map fst $                              -- recover the functions, `f` or `id`
          O.unionBy (comparing snd)         -- `is` is assumed subset of [0..]
                    (map (f  ,) is   )      -- tag with
                    (map (id ,) [0..]) )    --      indices
```

It's like `` getZipList $ (f `_at` is) `_or` (id `_at` [0..]) <*> ZipList xs `` with some ad-hoc definitions for `_at` and `_or`.

This uses the fact that `data-ordlist`'s `union` is left-biased, i.e. it picks the elements from its first argument list over those from its second, on collisions.

Comment: it's like ``getZipList $ (f `_at` is) `_or` (id `_at` [0..]) <*> ZipList xs`` with some ad-hoc definitions for `_at` and `_or`.

Comment: Great ! I have to admit that one is impressive. I was not aware of the possibility to use `unionBy` like this. And still working on the   `getZipList` thing ... BTW on the side of pedestrian code, I have added the  `zipWith`- based solution.

Comment: `ZipList` is just a tag we slap on our regular lists to convey the intent of *zipping* application: that `ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs == ZipList (zipWith ($) fs xs)` (a.o.t. the usual nested loop application, `fs <*> xs == [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]`). the tag is still there on the result, so we need to remove it: `getZipList (ZipList xs) == xs`. as usual in Haskell the naming is messed up: we do not get the ZipList, we get the regular list *inside* it. what I called tagging is usually referred to as wrapping. the wrap--unrwap thing is idiomatic.

Comment: btw I used the same idea of "looking from above" on two lists arranged "horizontally" one atop another,  in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970785/849891). (or vertically, and from the side, whatever feels right). :)