# How could I make a list in Haskell by prime index?

Tags: haskell

How could I make a list where I get every number/letter which has a prime index number?

```
primeIndex :: [a] -> [a]
primeIndex [1..20] == [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
primeIndex "primesarefun" == "rieau"
```

Comment: Take a look at the [*sieve of Eratosthenes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: This is really two questions in one. The first is how you find prime numbers in Haskell, and the second is how you filter a list by the elements' indices (as opposed to the usual case of filtering by their values). @WillemVanOnsem provided a link that will help with the first. Which of the pieces are you stuck on?

Comment: Why do you need the items at the prime indices..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A possible strategy:

Following the general approach mentioned above by @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, the problem can be solved like this:

1. get a list of all prime numbers, say `primes`
2. use that first list to create an auxiliary list of booleans which has `True` elements solely at prime indices
3. use the second list together with classic list functions (map, filter, zip) to solve the problem

Regarding the **first part**, there are a number of available algorithms in the [relevant page of the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers). We can just pick one of them.

```
import  Data.List.Ordered

_Y   :: (t -> t) -> t
_Y g = g (_Y g)    

joinL :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
joinL ((x:xs):t) = x : union xs (joinL t)
joinL ([]:t)     = joinL t
joinL  []        = []

primesLME :: [Integer]
primesLME = 2 : _Y ((3:) . minus [5,7..] . joinL . map (\p-> [p*p, p*p+2*p..]))

primes = primesLME
```

with LME standing for Linear MErging.

Regarding the **second part**, a function to transform `primes` into the required list of booleans, say `primeMask`, can be taken from [SO_q59092535](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59092535/11282404).

```
-- boolean list from index list (with unfoldr):
booleansFromIndices :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
booleansFromIndices indices =
    let  sfn (pos,ind) =  Just $  -- stepping function for unfoldr
             if (null ind)
               then ( False, (pos+1, []) )
               else ( pos==head ind,
                      (pos+1, if (pos==head ind)  then  tail ind  else  ind))
    in   unfoldr  sfn  (0,indices)

primeMask :: [Bool]
primeMask = drop 1 $ booleansFromIndices primes  -- 1-based indexing
```

### Putting it all together (third and last part):

In a `ghci` session:

```
 λ> 
 λ> take 10 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> take 15 primeMask
[False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,True,False,True,False,False]
 λ> 
 λ> take 20 $ map  (\b -> if b then '1' else '0')  primeMask
"01101010001010001010"
 λ> 
 λ> str = "primesarefun"
 λ> 
 λ> zip primeMask str
[(False,'p'),(True,'r'),(True,'i'),(False,'m'),(True,'e'),(False,'s'),(True,'a'),(False,'r'),(False,'e'),(False,'f'),(True,'u'),(False,'n')]
 λ> 
 λ> filter fst $ zip primeMask str
[(True,'r'),(True,'i'),(True,'e'),(True,'a'),(True,'u')]
 λ> 
 λ> map snd $ filter fst $ zip primeMask str
"rieau"
 λ> 
 λ> primeIndex = \xs -> map snd $ filter fst $ zip primeMask xs
 λ> 
 λ> primeIndex [1..20]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
 λ>
```